# importing library project + different projects into Android Studio from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, gradle, migration, android-gradle-plugin

Looks like the time has come for me to start using Android Studio, as I need some features that unfortunately have not been ported to Eclipse :(

Fortunately Android Studio is able to nearly-flawlessly import my projects, although I'm concerned if I'm doing it correctly

My Eclipse Workspace Layout is as follows:

- **LIB-CODEBASE** is a big **library project** that contains most of the application beef
- **APP-KINDLE** is a **runnable project** that uses the former, and provides some additional classes and activities for the KINDLE version of the app
- **APP-FIRETV** is the same, but targeted to Amazon FireTV devices
- **APP-GOOGLE** is the same, but targeted to Google-Play certified devices
- **APP-GCAST** is the same, but targeted to modern devices supporting Chromecast.

When I import into Android Studio any of the **APP-XXXX** projects, it creates a copy of **LIB-CODEBASE** inside. So for each **APP-XXXX** project I have a full copy of **LIB-CODEBASE** inside their folders.

Is there an easy way to make all **APP-XXXX** projects to just share, link or include the **LIB-CODEBASE** project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a project you can refer **an external module**.

Just use:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (application module)
   |__build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' 
include ':codeBaseLib'
project(':codeBaseLib').projectDir=new   File('pathLibrary')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':codeBaseLib')
}
```

Pay attention to codeBaseLib.
You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, **not the root** of the project.

Also for your APP-XXXX projects check if **you can use a single project** with different **[flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)**.

Comment: i ended up creating one project with one module for the common lib and one module for each APP-XXXX ... Gradle is definitely a different sport, but I'm loving it :) By the way, the eclipse projects were using a local GIT (accessed through the embedded eclipse GIT browser). Is it possible to migrate that GIT to the new Android Studio Project? (I created the project from scratch rather than importing to avoid problems)