# Using an Android Studio project as a library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a **project** in Android Studio (1.3.0) that will contain several modules and **will serve as a library** for other projects.

**Library Project:**

Inside my library, some modules have some dependencies on other modules (**intraproject dependency**). Let say `libmod1` has dependencies on `libmod2`. In *build.gradle* of `libmod1`, I have `compile project(':libmod2')`.

**Application Project:**

From an application project, I would like to import `libmod1` (**interproject dependency**). In *build.gradle*, I add `compile project(':..:LibProject:libmod1')`.

**Problem:**

When I build the application project, I get an error message from gradle:

> Error:(24, 0) Project with path ':libmod2' could not be found in
>   project ':..:LibProject:libmod1'.

**Gradle failed to resolve the intraproject dependency**.
I have to change the *build.gradle* of `libmod1` to `compile project(':..:LibProject:libmod2')` to get rid of this error. Meaning the intraproject dependencies must be changed when I reference them from another project.

**Question:**

**Is there a way to tell Gradle that the intraproject dependencies are relative to the library project and not relative to the application project ?** Such that when I have interproject dependencies on the library modules, the intraproject dependencies can be resolved ?

Of course, I could also remove the intraproject dependencies between the modules. But is there a different way to solve this problem ?

[image: Sketch of the situation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635143/importing-library-project-different-projects-into-android-studio-from-eclipse/33637705#33637705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the dependencies in your *settings.gradle*. If the modules are in the same folder its easy just connect them by

```
include ':libmod1',':libmod2'
```

If your libraries are located in other folders (not in any subfolder) you have to connect them in your *settings.gradle*:

```
project(':libmod1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../path/to/libmod1')
```

See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html